# Where can I find a table of the format string patterns usable by NSDateFormatter?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, datetime, string-formatting, date-formatting

An NSDateFormatter instance can have it's date and time formats set with:

```
[formatter setDateFormat: formatString];
```

Or you can have your format string localised with:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:
  [NSDateFormatter
    dateFormatFromTemplate: formatStringWithPatterns
    options: 0 
    locale: [NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

But where's a handy table of all the codes that can be used in format strings, giving examples of each's output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just pulled this out of Apple's docs because I can never find it when I need it. Hopefully S.O. will be better linked!

For the latest versions of iOS and OS X, the answer is:

- Formatters in OS X v10.8+ and iOS 6.0+, use version [tr35-25](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

For prior versions, you'll need to look more closely:

- Formatters in iOS 5.0-5.1 use version [tr35-19](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
- Formatters in OS X v10.7 and iOS 4.3 use version [tr35-17](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-17.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
- Formatters in iOS 4.0-4.2 use version [tr35-15](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-15.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
- Formatters in iOS 3.2 use version [tr35-12](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-12.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
- Formatters in OS X v10.6 and iOS 3.0-3.1 use version [tr35-10](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).